# Embedded systems file encryption library

Tags: c, encryption, filesystems, embedded

I've got a project and a part of it is incorporating encryption into a FAT file system.

The goal of the project is not the encryption, so I'm free to use open-source pre-done libraries.

Ideally what I'm after is a C library which uses RSA, that already has the methods for computing keys and encrypting/decrypting files.

Comment: What's your actual question, what are your design goals and are you sure it is a good fit for this forum?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to check out [NaCl](http://nacl.cr.yp.to/features.html) (pronounced as "salt"), especially since this is for an embedded system.

It has CPU-specific tunings and doesn't require any dynamic memory allocation.

As for licensing, the page (linked above) says "All of the NaCl software is in the public domain".

Comment: Thanks, been checking this out. Should hopefully be what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to give [blowfish](http://www.schneier.com/blowfish.html) a try. It's royalty free and there are [several open source C implementations](http://www.schneier.com/blowfish-download.html). It was created by [Bruce Schneier](http://www.schneier.com/about.html). Here is an [article](http://www.embedded.com/design/configurable-systems/4024599/Encrypting-data-with-the-Blowfish-algorithm) about using it with embedded systems.

Comment: Blowfish is not fast, especially on embedded systems.

Comment: Schneier is an impressive figure in the fawning tech news media. I'm not so impressed.

Comment: @GregS there is little wrong with Schneier, he was one of the group that created Skein, though I don't know his full involvement there. But I agree that he's more of a popular security expert than a cryptographer lately. This is clearly demonstrated by his blog. I'm not so sure if I would easily recommend blowfish though - there should be better options available.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding library - check [Cryptlib](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/cryptlib/) . It has dual license and includes quite a lot of functionality.

However, capability to encrypt files *right* depends on how you write the data and how you expect to do encryption.

Streaming encryption for streams with random access (i.e. when you need to encrypt-decrypt file data on the fly when it's written or read) is not a trivial task and requires certain knowledge of cryptography to employ correct encryption mode and do this right.

On the other hand if you have a file and want it encrypted, CryptLib has PKCS7/CMS implementation to do the job.