# 'Light' encrypt for socket tx in C

Tags: c, sockets, encryption

I have a socket server and client, both written in C.

These clients (multiple clients and one server) send information to the server, but these pieces of information must be as small as possible.

Currently, every 'packet' from the client is about 40-60 bytes and my client sends about 10 packets/second.

My protocol sends 2 bytes with packet size + payload + 2 bytes for 'end of TX', then the server compares the size + 2 bytes of EOT.

The size and two bytes of EOT are necessary because I can have those two bytes in the payload too, so size is considered too. This is working without any problem.

Now, I need to 'protect' this payload and I don't know how.

OpenSSL is not an option since I've made some tests and, using a 2048 byte certificate, the smallest 'encrypted' packet size is 256 bytes, even using 50 bytes as original data.

I don't need such strong encryption... in fact, something simple will be even better, since my client could run on embedded systems with low processing power. Probably something with one fixed 'key' on both ends would be perfect, but I don't have any idea how to do this or if there is already some standard method.

I think that any solution will increase my packet size... this is fine, but not from 50 bytes to 256 bytes (like using openSSL).

How can I protect the data with *at most* a moderate increase in the packet size?

Comment: BTW: the data is not 'readable'....I mean, is not text. Just bytes that I proccess in the server end.

Comment: Is your stream reliable (e.g. TCP) or unreliable (e.g. UDP)? There are plenty of ways to do this with AES, but how to build it best depends on whether each packet needs to be independent or whether you treat the entire connection as a "stream." Do you have access to a random number generator on the device, and is it practical to use regularly?

Comment: Well the simplest way is probably using something like DSA (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Signature_Algorithm) on some fixed-size blocks of bytes

Comment: @Dunno Why a signing algorithm rather than an encryption algorithm?

Comment: There is already a thread on SO for this. Here is the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124497/embedded-systems-file-encryption-library)
Hope it helps!

Comment: BTW, another algorithm that may meet your needs here (if you have a reliable connection) is ChaCha20 (or Salsa20). Since it's a stream cipher, you don't have to round it up to a block-size. If you have a library already that handles that, it may be a straightforward solution.

Comment: Rob, I'm using TCP and I didn't understand exactly what you asked about 'stream', abut My client makes a connections to server and then just send/receive packets as mentioned, taking care of EOT and size os packets (informed in the begining). I don't have dedicated device for random and I'll lok into ChaCha20 or Salsa20.

Comment: Ok, I think ChaCha20 is the most suitable for my needs. Not going offtopic, but ChaCha20 (imp. that I found) uses uint8_t * as input/putput....and I'm using char* for my data storage vefore transfer. Is safe to say that both are the same, IF I convert back to uint8_t and vice-versa on both ends?
ex: `char* abc;
uint8_t *def;
def = (uint_8)abc;
encrypt(def);
tx(def);
// Server
rx(def); `
same proccess, but convert from uint8_t back to char*.

Comment: On pretty much all modern systems (and on all POSIX systems), `char` and `uint8_t` are the same size, so it doesn't matter. You're just casting here (telling the compiler "it's ok, they have the same shape"), not converting anything.